# Java date time in arabic

Tags: java, spring, date, internationalization, arabic

How to get arabic date when the user selected language is Arabic and date in english format when selected language is english in spring application ? I tried by setting the default locale to english and arabic based on the request but this doesn't help me in getting calendar api time in arabic for (9 hours 15 mins).

Comment: Is your question about the locale (language) or the timezone?

Comment: If suppose i get (9 AM) in english in a lookup service i need corresponding value in arabic based on the user selected language in website.

Answer (score 2):

Use Joda time or Java 8 Date time API. Following is the example of Java 8 API

```
    if(language.equals("English")){
      LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
    else{        
      HijrahDate hijrahDate=HijrahDate.now();
    }
```

Comment: See also the Chronology.ofLocale(locale) method

Answer (score 1):

### Confused Question

Your question is confusing, and your comment did not help to clarify.

Did you want an [Islamic calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar)? If so, the [answer by Masud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19923775/642706) is correct.

Did you want to adjust the time zone of the date-time to an Arab location such as [Riyadh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riyadh)?

Did you want to localize the words used in the textual representation of a date-time, such as month and day name?

Did you want to localize the format of textual representation of a date-time, such as the order of presentation of day, month, year?

## Joda-Time

I'll just spin out a bit of example code using the Joda-Time 2.3 library, hoping it might help.

To create a [java.util.Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), you need:

- Language code (either, see [combined list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes))

  - ISO 639 [alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1)
  - ISO 639 [alpha-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2)
- Country Code (either)

  - [ISO 3166 alpha-2 country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)
  - [UN M.49 numeric-3 area code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UN_M.49)

### Example Code

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Riyadh" );
DateTime dateTimeRiyadh = dateTimeUtc.withZone( timeZone );

java.util.Locale locale = new Locale( "ar", "SA" ); // ( language code, country code );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( locale ).withZone( timeZone );
String output = formatter.print( dateTimeUtc );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeRiyadh: " + dateTimeRiyadh );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeUtc: 2014-02-16T09:52:33.901Z
dateTimeRiyadh: 2014-02-16T12:52:33.901+03:00
output: 16 فبراير, 2014 AST 12:52:33 م
```