# Android, Right way to programticly format date time as time ago

Tags: android, datetime, time, android-date

Example, from 1 min ago
i use api and time response result from Api service as:

```
{
  "date_time":"2016-03-10 03:20:30"
}
```

Please discuss step by step, And if available how can programticly display it in Arabic format
منذ 15 دقيقة

My Code for date in list view adapter

```
 TextView date_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_time_list_home);
 date_time.setText(m.dateTime());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time ago for Android/java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174921/time-ago-for-android-java)

Comment: What format is `4-2-3 2:0:1`?

Comment: "date":"2016-09-19 07:24:13" this format from mysql db, Sorry iam new for android and i can not understand solution of ur  link

Comment: Is `m.dateTime()` a `String`, a `Date` or some other class?

Comment: Its Getter from claasModel fetch date from my api

Comment: Also duplicate of: [Java date time in arabic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19923498/642706). Please **search Stack Overflow before posting**. A Stack Exchange is meant to be more like Wikipedia and less like an endless discussion forum.

Answer (score 3):

First, for any date/time manipulation on Android, I highly recommend using the [`ThreeTenABP`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library. This is a back port of the Java 8 `java.time.*` package, circumventing the notoriously disappointing `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes.

To parse your `"date_time"` using this library, you can use the following code:

```
// I set the ZoneId to systemDefault, but you should really use the ZoneId of the server
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                                  .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
                                  .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()); 

Instant instant = formatter.parse(m.dateTime(), Instant.FROM);
```

Android provides the [`DateUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) class to display date and time information. This class takes into account system settings such as [`Locale`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) and 12/24-hour format. Therefore, if the `Locale` of the device is set to any of the Arabic locales (`ar_`), the date/time will be displayed in a format suited for it.

```
String display = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                        instant.toEpochMilli(),
                        Instant.now().toEpochMilli(),
                        DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

date_time.setText(display);
```

The last parameter in `getRelativeTimeSpanString` is the minimum resolution, so setting `DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS` will not display the difference in seconds.

---

If you insist on using the Java 7 classes, here is the same code using them:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(m.dateTime());

String display = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                        date.getTime(),
                        new Date(),
                        DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

date_time.setText(display);
```

---

If you need a "transition resolution" greater than a single day (i.e. you want to display a date/time that is further than one day in the past as "… days ago") you can use the [`DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeDateTimeString(android.content.Context,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20int)) method instead:

```
String display = DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(
                        mContext,
                        instant.toEpochMilli(),
                        DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
                        DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS,
                        DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);
```

Any date that is further back than the `transitionResolution` (in this case, one week) will be displayed in an appropriate date format, instead of the relative format. The `minResolution` and `transitionResolution` can be any `long` value, `DateUtils` contains other convenient constants such as `MONTH_IN_MILLIS` and `YEAR_IN_MILLIS`.

The last parameter takes an integer for formatting flags. These flags override the default formatting that `DateUtils` uses for each `Locale`; view the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks for nice code, I use  ThreeTenABP Lbrary but it format date to Sep 19, 2016 and i want it to format as time ago same ( 19 min ago )

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding your statement. It sounds like you are using the `ThreeTenABP` library to format the text, and not `DateUtils`? The method I use above (`formatter.parse()`) is to translate your date/time string (`m.dateTime()`) into an `Instant`, or a specific point in time. This is *not* meant to be used to display the date/time on screen. Then I use `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()` to get a `String` representation of that time as some time ago (i.e. "19 mins ago").

Comment: I use this code:
`String display =(String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                        date.getTime(),
                        new Date(),
                        DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

date_time.setText(display);`
and result in screen : `Sep 19, 2016` , Not: 19 min ago, Understand me!

Comment: @MohamedAbozaid Oh, okay. I forgot that `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()` will display the relative `String` in that format if both times are not within the same day. Try a date/time within the current day. If you need it to display something like "15 days ago" instead of "Sep 19, 2016", use `getRelativeDateTimeString()`. I will update with information regarding that method.

Comment: Give me error
`Error:(107, 35) error: method getRelativeDateTimeString in class DateUtils cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,long,long,long,int
found: long,long,long
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`
I think miss context paramter and int paramter

Comment: @MohamedAbozaid Yes, it looks like you are missing the two other parameters. `DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString()` takes a `Context`, a `long` value for the time in question, a `long` value for the minimum resolution, a `long` value for the transition resolution, and an `int` value for the format flags.