# I am trying to convert an arabic Time into English Time

Tags: java

I am trying to convert an Arabic Time to Englist Time can anyone help me on this.

Example :- The Arabic Time is 12:30 صباحاً

The English Time should be 12.30 AM

Comment: Can you read this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923498/java-date-time-in-arabic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java date time in arabic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923498/java-date-time-in-arabic)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `DateFormat` with an arabic `Locale` to parse the original `String` to a `Date`, then a `DateFormat` with `Locale.ENGLISH` to convert to an english `String` :

```
DateFormat formatArabic = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", new Locale("ar", "SA"));
DateFormat formatEnglish = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.ENGLISH);

try {

    Date date = formatArabic.parse("12:30 صباحاً");

    System.out.println(formatEnglish.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```